# ResourceId not found in separate Android Assembly

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-resources

I have a Xamarin Droid project. I created a separate android library assembly and i put all my resource files (layouts, drawables, styles, ...) into that separate assembly. So no layouts are in the droid project itself.

When i try to access resources using there id, I get an exception `Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: String resource ID 0x....`

this happens for calls like `GetString(Resource.String.app_name)`. Also, when i try to find views by there id `this.FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.navigationView);` the return value is always `null`

The separation is part of a refactoring. Before the refactoring, every resource was referenced from the main droid project, but due to an enhancement concept we have to provide for our customers, we had to move layouts, views, ... to a separate assembly.

Comment: May be a silly question, but are you sure you have the correct "Resource" namespace?  I have been hit by this in the past.

Comment: you are right, for laziness, i did not change the namespace for the "UI" assembly, so namespace of application and UI assembly was the same; that seems a bad idea. changed the namespaces, resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the namespace for the "Resource" class is the one you intended to target.

There will be several of these, especially if you have more than one android assembly.